# Return everything after phrase, to end of string, excluding phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following URL

```
https://website.com?id=XXXVVVCCCHHH
```

I only want `XXXVVVCCCHHH`, I've tried the following:

```
var phrase = 'https://website.com?id=XXXVVVCCCHHH'; 
var myRegexp = /id=(.*)/;
phrase = myRegexp.exec(phrase);
```

But this is returning: `id=XXXVVVCCCHHH`;

How can Ii edit this to only return `XXXVVVCCCHHH`?

Comment: phrase = myRegexp.exec(phrase)[1];

Comment: Your solution is already working well. Just access the right group value.

Comment: `id=(.*?)(?=$|[&#])` in the case another get variable or fragment may be present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use *split* and take the second element:

```js
var url = "https://website.com?id=XXXVVVCCCHHH";
var part = url.split('=')[1];
console.log(part);
```